# WordPress remove <br/> separator from last item in wp_list_categories

Tags: php, html, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to remove the last separator (normally a `<br/>` tag but I changed it to "//") from the last link from wp_list_categories.

Basically I want this:

Category 1 // Category 2 // Category 3 //

to look like this:

Category 1 // Category 2 // Category 3

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
<?php
$cat_array = array();
$args=array(
 'author' => get_the_author_meta('id'),
 'showposts'=>-1,
 'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$author_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $author_posts ) {
  foreach ($author_posts as $author_post ) {
    foreach(get_the_category($author_post->ID) as $category) {
      $cat_array[$category->term_id] =  $category->term_id;
    }
  }
}

$cat_ids = implode(',', $cat_array);
echo strtr(wp_list_categories('include='.$cat_ids.'&title_li=&style=none&echo=0'),array('<br />'=>' // '));
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This could be well suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/646/wordpress-remove-br-separator-from-last-item-in-wp-list-categories

```
$output = strtr( wp_list_categories( 'include='.$cat_ids.'&title_li=&style=none&echo=0' ), array( '<br />' => ' // ' ) );
echo preg_replace( '@\s//\s\n$@', '', $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim:

`trim(wp_list_categories('include='.$cat_ids.'&title_li=&style=none&echo=0'), '/')`

Comment: this didn't seem to work, should i be placing this directly after the echo strtr line at the end?

Answer (score -3):

replace the contents of nav-menu-template.php with

```
<?php
/**
 * Navigation Menu template functions
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 3.0.0
 */

/**
 * Create HTML list of nav menu items.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @uses Walker
 */
class Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {
    /**
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     */
    var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     */
    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
     */
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Used for padding.
     */
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';


        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

        $item_output .= '</a>';
        if (!strstr( $class_names, "menu-item-last" ) )
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
     */
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}

/**
 * Displays a navigation menu.
 *
 * Optional $args contents:
 *
 * menu - The menu that is desired.  Accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name. Defaults to blank.
 * menu_class - CSS class to use for the ul element which forms the menu. Defaults to 'menu'.
 * menu_id - The ID that is applied to the ul element which forms the menu. Defaults to the menu slug, incremented.
 * container - Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Defaults to 'div'.
 * container_class - the class that is applied to the container. Defaults to 'menu-{menu slug}-container'.
 * container_id - The ID that is applied to the container. Defaults to blank.
 * fallback_cb - If the menu doesn't exists, a callback function will fire. Defaults to 'wp_page_menu'. Set to false for no fallback.
 * before - Text before the link text.
 * after - Text after the link text.
 * link_before - Text before the link.
 * link_after - Text after the link.
 * echo - Whether to echo the menu or return it. Defaults to echo.
 * depth - how many levels of the hierarchy are to be included.  0 means all.  Defaults to 0.
 * walker - allows a custom walker to be specified.
 * theme_location - the location in the theme to be used.  Must be registered with register_nav_menu() in order to be selectable by the user.
 * items_wrap - How the list items should be wrapped. Defaults to a ul with an id and class. Uses printf() format with numbered placeholders.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param array $args Arguments
 */
function wp_nav_menu( $args = array() ) {
    static $menu_id_slugs = array();

    $defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
    $args = (object) $args;

    // Get the nav menu based on the requested menu
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

    // Get the nav menu based on the theme_location
    if ( ! $menu && $args->theme_location && ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $args->theme_location ] ) )
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $args->theme_location ] );

    // get the first menu that has items if we still can't find a menu
    if ( ! $menu && !$args->theme_location ) {
        $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
        foreach ( $menus as $menu_maybe ) {
            if ( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_maybe->term_id) ) {
                $menu = $menu_maybe;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If the menu exists, get its items.
    if ( $menu && ! is_wp_error($menu) && !isset($menu_items) )
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );

    // If no menu was found or if the menu has no items and no location was requested, call the fallback_cb if it exists
    if ( ( !$menu || is_wp_error($menu) || ( isset($menu_items) && empty($menu_items) && !$args->theme_location ) )
        && $args->fallback_cb && is_callable( $args->fallback_cb ) )
            return call_user_func( $args->fallback_cb, (array) $args );

    // If no fallback function was specified and the menu doesn't exists, bail.
    if ( !$menu || is_wp_error($menu) )
        return false;

    $nav_menu = $items = '';

    $show_container = false;
    if ( $args->container ) {
        $allowed_tags = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'div', 'nav' ) );
        if ( in_array( $args->container, $allowed_tags ) ) {
            $show_container = true;
            $class = $args->container_class ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $args->container_class ) . '"' : ' class="menu-'. $menu->slug .'-container"';
            $id = $args->container_id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args->container_id ) . '"' : '';
            $nav_menu .= '<'. $args->container . $id . $class . '>';
        }
    }

    // Set up the $menu_item variables
    _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( $menu_items );

    $sorted_menu_items = array();
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item )
        $sorted_menu_items[$menu_item->menu_order] = $menu_item;

    unset($menu_items);

    $sorted_menu_items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', $sorted_menu_items, $args );

    $items .= walk_nav_menu_tree( $sorted_menu_items, $args->depth, $args );
    unset($sorted_menu_items);

    // Attributes
    if ( ! empty( $args->menu_id ) ) {
        $wrap_id = $args->menu_id;
    } else {
        $wrap_id = 'menu-' . $menu->slug;
        while ( in_array( $wrap_id, $menu_id_slugs ) ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#-(\d+)$#', $wrap_id, $matches ) )
                $wrap_id = preg_replace('#-(\d+)$#', '-' . ++$matches[1], $wrap_id );
            else
                $wrap_id = $wrap_id . '-1';
        }
    }
    $menu_id_slugs[] = $wrap_id;

    $wrap_class = $args->menu_class ? $args->menu_class : '';

    // Allow plugins to hook into the menu to add their own <li>'s
    $items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_items', $items, $args );
    $items = apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args );

    $nav_menu .= sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );
    unset( $items );

    if ( $show_container )
        $nav_menu .= '</' . $args->container . '>';

    $nav_menu = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu', $nav_menu, $args );

    if ( $args->echo )
        echo $nav_menu;
    else
        return $nav_menu;
}

/**
 * Add the class property classes for the current context, if applicable.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 3.0
 *
 * @param array $menu_items The current menu item objects to which to add the class property information.
 */
function _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( &$menu_items ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $queried_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $queried_object_id = (int) $wp_query->queried_object_id;

    $active_object = '';
    $active_ancestor_item_ids = array();
    $active_parent_item_ids = array();
    $active_parent_object_ids = array();
    $possible_taxonomy_ancestors = array();
    $possible_object_parents = array();
    $home_page_id = (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

    if ( $wp_query->is_singular && ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) && ! is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) get_object_taxonomies( $queried_object->post_type ) as $taxonomy ) {
            if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) ) {
                $term_hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy( $taxonomy );
                $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $queried_object_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                if ( is_array( $terms ) ) {
                    $possible_object_parents = array_merge( $possible_object_parents, $terms );
                    $term_to_ancestor = array();
                    foreach ( (array) $term_hierarchy as $anc => $descs ) {
                        foreach ( (array) $descs as $desc )
                            $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] = $anc;
                    }

                    foreach ( $terms as $desc ) {
                        do {
                            $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $taxonomy ][] = $desc;
                            if ( isset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] ) ) {
                                $_desc = $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ];
                                unset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] );
                                $desc = $_desc;
                            } else {
                                $desc = 0;
                            }
                        } while ( ! empty( $desc ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) && is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) ) {
        _get_post_ancestors( $queried_object );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $queried_object->taxonomy ) && is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $queried_object->taxonomy ) ) {
        $term_hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy( $queried_object->taxonomy );
        $term_to_ancestor = array();
        foreach ( (array) $term_hierarchy as $anc => $descs ) {
            foreach ( (array) $descs as $desc )
                $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] = $anc;
        }
        $desc = $queried_object->term_id;
        do {
            $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $queried_object->taxonomy ][] = $desc;
            if ( isset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] ) ) {
                $_desc = $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ];
                unset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] );
                $desc = $_desc;
            } else {
                $desc = 0;
            }
        } while ( ! empty( $desc ) );
    }

    $possible_object_parents = array_filter( $possible_object_parents );

    $front_page_url = home_url();
    $menu__items = (array) $menu_items;
    $total_menu__items = count($menu__items);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {

        $menu_items[$key]->current = false;

        $classes = (array) $menu_item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-type-' . $menu_item->type;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-object-' . $menu_item->object;
        if($i == $total_menu__items)
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-last';
        $i++;
        // if the menu item corresponds to a taxonomy term for the currently-queried non-hierarchical post object
        if ( $wp_query->is_singular && 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type && in_array( $menu_item->object_id, $possible_object_parents ) ) {
            $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->object_id;
            $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->db_id;
            $active_object = $queried_object->post_type;

        // if the menu item corresponds to the currently-queried post or taxonomy object
        } elseif (
            $menu_item->object_id == $queried_object_id &&
            (
                ( ! empty( $home_page_id ) && 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_home && $home_page_id == $menu_item->object_id ) ||
                ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_singular ) ||
                ( 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type && ( $wp_query->is_category || $wp_query->is_tag || $wp_query->is_tax ) )
            )
        ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            $menu_items[$key]->current = true;
            $_anc_id = (int) $menu_item->db_id;

            while(
                ( $_anc_id = get_post_meta( $_anc_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true ) ) &&
                ! in_array( $_anc_id, $active_ancestor_item_ids )
            ) {
                $active_ancestor_item_ids[] = $_anc_id;
            }

            if ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && 'page' == $menu_item->object ) {
                // Back compat classes for pages to match wp_page_menu()
                $classes[] = 'page_item';
                $classes[] = 'page-item-' . $menu_item->object_id;
                $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
            }
            $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->post_parent;
            $active_object = $menu_item->object;

        // if the menu item corresponds to the currently-requested URL
        } elseif ( 'custom' == $menu_item->object ) {
            $current_url = untrailingslashit( ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            $item_url = untrailingslashit( strpos( $menu_item->url, '#' ) ? substr( $menu_item->url, 0, strpos( $menu_item->url, '#' ) ) : $menu_item->url );
            $_indexless_current = untrailingslashit( preg_replace( '/index.php$/', '', $current_url ) );

            if ( in_array( $item_url, array( $current_url, $_indexless_current ) ) ) {
                $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
                $menu_items[$key]->current = true;
                $_anc_id = (int) $menu_item->db_id;

                while(
                    ( $_anc_id = get_post_meta( $_anc_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true ) ) &&
                    ! in_array( $_anc_id, $active_ancestor_item_ids )
                ) {
                    $active_ancestor_item_ids[] = $_anc_id;
                }

                if ( in_array( home_url(), array( untrailingslashit( $current_url ), untrailingslashit( $_indexless_current ) ) ) ) {
                    // Back compat for home link to match wp_page_menu()
                    $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
                }
                $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
                $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->post_parent;
                $active_object = $menu_item->object;

            // give front page item current-menu-item class when extra query arguments involved
            } elseif ( $item_url == $front_page_url && is_front_page() ) {
                $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            }

            if ( untrailingslashit($item_url) == home_url() )
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-home';
        }

        // back-compat with wp_page_menu: add "current_page_parent" to static home page link for any non-page query
        if ( ! empty( $home_page_id ) && 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && empty( $wp_query->is_page ) && $home_page_id == $menu_item->object_id )
            $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';

        $menu_items[$key]->classes = array_unique( $classes );
    }
    $active_ancestor_item_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_ancestor_item_ids ) );
    $active_parent_item_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_parent_item_ids ) );
    $active_parent_object_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_parent_object_ids ) );

    // set parent's class
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $parent_item ) {
        $classes = (array) $parent_item->classes;
        $menu_items[$key]->current_item_ancestor = false;
        $menu_items[$key]->current_item_parent = false;

        if (
            isset( $parent_item->type ) &&
            (
                // ancestral post object
                (
                    'post_type' == $parent_item->type &&
                    ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $queried_object->ancestors ) &&
                    $parent_item->object != $queried_object->ID
                ) ||

                // ancestral term
                (
                    'taxonomy' == $parent_item->type &&
                    isset( $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    (
                        ! isset( $queried_object->term_id ) ||
                        $parent_item->object_id != $queried_object->term_id
                    )
                )
            )
        ) {
            $classes[] = empty( $queried_object->taxonomy ) ? 'current-' . $queried_object->post_type . '-ancestor' : 'current-' . $queried_object->taxonomy . '-ancestor';
        }

        if ( in_array(  intval( $parent_item->db_id ), $active_ancestor_item_ids ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
            $menu_items[$key]->current_item_ancestor = true;
        }
        if ( in_array( $parent_item->db_id, $active_parent_item_ids ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-parent';
            $menu_items[$key]->current_item_parent = true;
        }
        if ( in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $active_parent_object_ids ) )
            $classes[] = 'current-' . $active_object . '-parent';

        if ( 'post_type' == $parent_item->type && 'page' == $parent_item->object ) {
            // Back compat classes for pages to match wp_page_menu()
            if ( in_array('current-menu-parent', $classes) )
                $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
            if ( in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $classes) )
                $classes[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        }

        $menu_items[$key]->classes = array_unique( $classes );
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieve the HTML list content for nav menu items.
 *
 * @uses Walker_Nav_Menu to create HTML list content.
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @see Walker::walk() for parameters and return description.
 */
function walk_nav_menu_tree( $items, $depth, $r ) {
    $walker = ( empty($r->walker) ) ? new Walker_Nav_Menu : $r->walker;
    $args = array( $items, $depth, $r );

    return call_user_func_array( array(&$walker, 'walk'), $args );
}

/**
 * Prevents a menu item ID from being used more than once.
 *
 * @since 3.0.1
 * @access private
 */
function _nav_menu_item_id_use_once( $id, $item ) {
    static $_used_ids = array();
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $_used_ids ) )
        return '';
    $_used_ids[] = $item->ID;
    return $id;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', '_nav_menu_item_id_use_once', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That's a humongous code segment. Trim it down to the relevant parts.